# Convert from Unicode to UTF8

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8

i'm using C# 2010, want to convert textBox2.Text into UTF8 string...

```
byte[] utf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox2.Text);
        byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox2.Text);
        String str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
//            MessageBox.Show(str);
        //sTopicNewsTxt = "-1 RENDERER*TREE*@TOP_NEWS_DATA01*GEOM*TEXT SET "  +          Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
        //MessageBox.Show(sTopicNewsTxt);            
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        //byte[] var = utf8.GetBytes(textBox2.Text);
        sTopicNewsTxt = "-1 RENDERER*TREE*@TOP_NEWS_DATA01*GEOM*TEXT SET " + Convert.ToString(utf[0]);
```

I'm using Hindi utf8 font...

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: So what's your question?  (And why are you doing all this unnecessary conversion back and forth between `String` and `byte[]`?)

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` is the right (or at least one of the right) method to use: please describe in what way this is not working for you.

Comment: What is the end result you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

You had your result at the first line into the method. `utf8Bytes` *is* your text in UTF-8 encoding.

There is no such thing as a "UTF-8 string" in .NET. Strings are Unicode (UTF-16) behind the scenes. If you are talking about specific encodings, you're back down to byte arrays. Don't confuse the two.

Comment: Exactly. It's not string who has the encoding, it's bytes.